# fill longer variable according to shorter df conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two data frames one with the correct answers and a longer one (more rows) with all the answers from a survey.
I would like to substitute the right answers in one column of the survey data frame. The problem is that they have different lengths.

Here an example code, of course the function doesn't work:

```
##correct answers df    
species_common <- c("algarrobo", "sapote", "palo santo", "tara", "faique", "caoba", "teca", "neem",
                    "tamarindo", "hualtaco", "guayacan", "eucalyptus", "abarco", "cedro", "caoba", "choiba", 
                    "fresno", "balsa", "acacia", "teca", "melina", "saman", "piñon de oreja", "abarco", 
                    "ceibo", "ebano", "balsa", "ceiba tolúa", "eucalyptus", "teca")
spec_country <- c(rep("Peru",12), rep("Colombia",18))
ecoregion <- c(rep("Dry", 12), rep("Wet", 10), rep("Dry", 8))
species <- as.data.frame(cbind(species_common, spec_country, ecoregion))

##survey df
species_common_2 <- rep(c("algarrobo", "sapote", "palo santo", "tara", "faique", "caoba", "teca", "neem",
                        "tamarindo", "hualtaco", "guayacan", "eucalyptus", "abarco", "cedro", "caoba", "choiba", 
                        "fresno", "balsa", "acacia", "teca", "melina", "saman", "piñon de oreja", "abarco", 
                        "ceibo", "ebano", "balsa", "ceiba tolúa", "eucalyptus", "teca"), 4)
spec_country_2 <- rep(c(rep("Peru",12), rep("Colombia",18), rep(NA, 90)))
ecoregion_2 <- rep(c(rep("Dry", 12), rep("Wet", 10), rep("Dry", 8)),4)
survey <- as.data.frame(cbind(species_common_2, spec_country_2, ecoregion_2))
rows <- sample(nrow(survey))
survey <- survey[rows,]

## ideal function to match cases in order to fill the country column
survey$spec_country_2 <- ifelse(survey$species_common_2==species$species_common & 
                                        survey$ecoregion_2==species$ecoregion,
                                 species$spec_country, survey$spec_country)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach to do these types of analysis is to use [joins](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html). In your case, the desired output can be achieved using leftjoin and followed by ifelse. Your dataset `species` is not unique at `species_common` and `ecoregion level`, which you need to consider first. Example: which spec_country to the given preference for the combination of teca and Dry?

```
species %>% filter(species_common=="teca")
  species_common spec_country ecoregion
1           teca         Peru       Dry
2           teca     Colombia       Wet
3           teca     Colombia       Dry
```

The logic to reach the desired output:

```
survey<-survey %>% unique() # remove duplicated rows if any

masterDt<- survey %>% left_join(species,by=c("species_common_2"="species_common","ecoregion_2"="ecoregion"))

masterDt$spec_country_2_Updated<- ifelse(!is.na(masterDt$spec_country_2),masterDt$spec_country)
```

Comment: I cannot remove duplicated rows, it's a survey.

Comment: No probs you can comment on those lines, the more important points are concepts

Comment: If my suggestion suitably answers your question, click the tick mark to accept it as the chosen answer.

Comment: Glad to  help! .